# Get sum of due_amount for each date for this week in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I want to get the weekly/monthly/yearly report and in that report, I need to get the total of the field due_amount on daily basis for this week/month/year

I need something like
Sunday => 1000 (due_amount 500+500)
Monday => 1200
Tuesday => 500
upto Saturday(end of week)

If its monthly then from 1st to 31st and if it is yearly then Jan Feb to December.

What I do is

```
Invoice.group(&:week).where('due_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', date_range[:current_start_date].to_date, date_range[:current_end_date].to_date).sum(:due_amount)
```

but its not working

I can also do date_trunc('week', ) but I do not know how to do it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution - add the [gem groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) and you will be able to do something like

```
Invoice.group_by_day(:due_date, range: 2.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.now).map(&:due_amount).sum
```

Comment: Thanks but I know that, I do not want to add gem for the queries

Comment: well, than it's your take :)